# windows script to copy text from one file into a new file

Tags: windows-7, script, batch-file, copy-paste, help-files

I am noob at coding! I am trying to create a windows script that I can copy text from one file into another. My main goal is to find lines in the text with "started processing" and "file". I am hoping I can make this a batch file! If someone can help I would be very grateful.

Thanks

P.S. I am using Windows 7 Server edition

Comment: Have you tried to use FINDSTR and redirect the output to a file?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using PowerShell instead of Batch. It is much more powerful and easier.

The only commands you need are [`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849787%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) and [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx):

```
Get-Content in.txt | Where-Object { $_ -match "started processing" -or $_ -match "file" } >> out.txt
```

This will copy all lines containing either "started processing" or "match" to a file called "out.txt".